# Regex starts with "ATG" ends with "TAG, TAA orTGA" but does not contain "ATG" and "TAG, TAA or TGA" in between

Tags: java, regex

I'm searching for patterns in a String starting with `ATG`, ending with `TAG, TAA or TGA` and length = multiple of 3. `ATG` and `TAG, TAA or TGA` can only appear at respectively beginning or end. Which means:

From `ATGTTGTGATGT` extract `ATGTTGTGA`

From `ATGATGTTGTGATGT` extract `ATGTTGTGA`

Currently I'm using regex `(ATG)([ATG]{3})+?(TAG|TAA|TGA)`.

For `ATGATGTTGTGATGT` this gets me the wrong result `ATGATGTTGTGA`.
I've tried:

```
(^ATG)(!?=.*ATG)([ATG]{3})+?(TAG|TAA|TGA)
(^ATG)(!?=(ATG)+)([ATG]{3})+?(TAG|TAA|TGA)
```

How to tell it to contain `ATG` only once in the beginning and no more after that?

Comment: Your first example does not seems to match your description: it doesn't end with TAG|TAA|TGA?

Comment: This is not possible with regexp. You could do a *negative search* for `ATG` being not first or last and *negate* this result.

Comment: Try [`ATG(?:(?!ATG)[ATG]{3})*?(?:TAG|TAA|TGA)`](https://regex101.com/r/GCdGs8/1)

Comment: @Ward : I modified the question. Hopefully it's more clear now.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew : This does exactly what I was looking for in the question

Comment: @xtra Great, I posted as an answer with demos and expanation.

Comment: If you're parsing nucleotides, you should probably use a library designed to work with them instead of going for raw regular expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
ATG(?:(?!ATG)[ATG]{3})*?(?:TAG|TAA|TGA)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GCdGs8/1)

**Details**

- `ATG` - an `ATG` substring
- `(?:(?!ATG)[ATG]{3})*?` - a [tempered greedy token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30900794/tempered-greedy-token-what-is-different-about-placing-the-dot-before-the-negat) matching any sequence of 3 chars from the `[ATG]` character set that is not equal to `ATG` (that is restricted with the [negative lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?!ATG)`)
- `(?:TAG|TAA|TGA)` - either of the three alternatives defined in the [non-capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-what-does-a-question-mark-followed-by-a-colon): `TAG`, `TAA` or `TGA`.

[Java demo](https://ideone.com/zk47lb):

```
String rx = "ATG(?:(?!ATG)[ATG]{3})*?(?:TAG|TAA|TGA)";
String s = "ATGTTGTGATGT, ATGATGTTGTGATGT, ATGATGTTGTGATGT";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(rx);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
}
```

Result:

```
ATGTTGTGA
ATGTTGTGA
ATGTTGTGA
```